# Beginner Python user - need help iterating through a column in a MySQL db and store the values in a list

Tags: python, mysql-python

The python code below connects to my database. What I'm trying to do is iterate through a column which contains integer values, and put all of those values into a list. I will need the values in the list because I want to normalise them between a range of 0 and 1.

```
import MySQLdb
import sys

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="****", user="****", passwd="****", db="****", port=3306)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT columnName FROM TABLE5")

col1 = []
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
for x in range(0,numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    col1.append(row[x])
    print col1

cursor.close()
db.close()
sys.exit()
```

The above currently outputs the following:

```
[('67',)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "miner.py", line 12, in <module>
  col1.append(row[x])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

If anyone could help that would be great!

Comment: I think you're iterating the rows, but trying to read the column with the rowindex.

Comment: Look at your code and the error you are given: You say `for x in range(numrows)` (which has to do with how many rows you have) then try to get `row[x]`. If you have 100,000 rows with 3 columns each, do you see why this will fail by the 4th row?

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT columnName FROM TABLE5")
col_names = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

is probably what you want `cursor.fechall()` will return something like

```
[("ColName1",),("Colname2",),...]
```

so we just iterate over that list and take the first item from each tuple

you could also do something fancy like

```
col_names = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(cursor.fetchall()))
```

but really the simple list comprehesion should be plenty sufficient

Comment: Thank you Joran, this is what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused about the use of `cursor.fetchall()`.  I'm guessing you think it will return all the columns for a single row.  But really it returns *all the rows* from the query you executed.

Therefore, you need to execute `cursor.fetchall()` only once, outside your loop.

Additionally, while your loop (or rather, something close to it) will work, it's unnecessarily complex and "un-Pythonic".  That's because the results of `fetchall()` (a list of all the rows) can be directly iterated over without worrying about the count.  It iteration will produce a single row object, which contains the columns you want.  So:

```
col1 = []
all_the_rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in all_the_rows:
    # We want the first-and-only column value in the row
    col1.append(row[0])

 # Wait until we have all the values to print them.
print col1
```

You can simplify this further (Joran has an example above), but it may be best to start with a regular for-loop construction and move on to the advanced concepts once you have this nailed down.